# Cloudfront path logic to serve different pages from the same origin (S3 bucket)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket that is served via a CloudFront distribution, and I want to have some simple route logic to send different paths to specific S3 files. So for example, domain.com/colors/* would go to the domain.com/rainbow, while domain.com/numbers/* would go somewhere else, let's say domain.com/math.

Currently I've achieved something kind of like this by setting the 404 error page to the page I want served, but there is no logic here; all 404s go to the same place. So I essentially want to have more granular control over the error logic in my CloudFront distribution.

I've read about this being achieved by setting different paths to different origins, but I only have (and only want to have) one single origin, which is the S3 bucket.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You probably need Lambda@Edge to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Lambda@Edge to get this functionality. This sample from AWS is very similar code to what I ended up using: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-a-b-testing